# How to cluster multiple marker in map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-android-api-2

I am creating one map application where i want to show many markers. 
But the problem is that when markers are shown on map there are more than 100 markers at same area so all are not visible clearly.

So i want to make cluster of that marker so all marker are visible properly.
I visit many links for that but it does not work for me

So please help me

Comment: Visually, you are never going to be able to see 100 markers at the same place. Are you wanting to create 1 big marker that separates as the user zooms in? Are you wanting to create a single marker that is a different colour depending on how many markers it represents?

Comment: You can use this library for clustering 
https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions

Comment: You can look at Google documents for example also  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: @JenB actually i want to do something like you say i implement code but it does not show me accurate result

Comment: I need code snippet for this